# Filling Textbox, when combobox Selected Index Changed

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox

In the code below, i just want to fill my textbox based on the selected combo box changed. but i get the following error.

> 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value
>   'System.Data.DataRowViewConvert.ToString()' to data type int.'

i'd appreciate it if you help me.

```
SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\UniversityDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        private void comboBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "SELECT *FROM TutorTable";
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, objConnection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SDA.Fill(dt);
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Tid";
            objConnection.Close();
        }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT *FROM TutorTable where Tid = '"+comboBox1.Text+ "Convert.ToString()'";
        SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, objConnection);
        objConnection.Open();
        objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string Tname = (string)dr["Tname"].ToString();
            textBox1.Text = Tname;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using the Convert.ToString() in this piece of code:

```
"SELECT * FROM TutorTable where Tid = '"+comboBox1.Text+ "Convert.ToString()'"
```

I think the correct way wolud be:

```
"SELECT * FROM TutorTable where Tid = '"+comboBox1.Text+ "'"
```

But consider using a store procedure to prevent sql injection or using an ORM.

I think that `comboBox1.Text` is already returning a string value. So if that, it is not necessary to put the `Convert.ToString(comboBox.Text)`, just put comboBox1.Text

According to documentation, the Text property is a string
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jcvegan i removed the convert.ToString(); but the code is not still working

Comment: @Sina can you tell me what is the value of sqlQuery after made the concat?

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution as follows:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\UniversityDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT *FROM TutorTable WHERE Tid = '" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string name = (string)dr["Tname"].ToString();
            textBox1.Text = name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got the answer already but few more things should be taken care of

Your code

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sqlQuery = "SELECT *FROM TutorTable where Tid = '"+comboBox1.Text+ "Convert.ToString()'";
    SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, objConnection);
    objConnection.Open();
    objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        string Tname = (string)dr["Tname"].ToString();
        textBox1.Text = Tname;
    }

}
```

Things to notice:

1) Use varabled instead of manipulating sql
e.g. `SELECT *FROM TutorTable where Tid = @id` and pass id into sqlCommand object

2) You dont need to call `ExecuteNonQuery` before `SqlDataReader`

3) you need to use `if(dr.Read()`) instead of `while`

4) You can directly assign value textbox. 
e.g. `texBox1.Text = dr["Tname"].ToString();`

5) Close the `objConnection`

Comment: Thansk for your advice